# Is sqlmap tracable?

Tags: penetration-test, sql-injection

The question is simple. For example, we access a database of any website. And looked up for datas. So, is the website owner can see me? If he/she can see, how can i protect?

[These are for security of course. I'm trying to think as the bad boy]

Thanks for answering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand if your request is about general logging of website DBMSs or the tracEability of SQLMap:

- First, being an SQL injection test, you will be generating requests that are not permitted and queries to tables that are not supposed to be accessed from the outside. Those are http requests so they will be logged by the webserver.
- Generally speaking, it is simple to configure the database to log all the accesses, so if you lookup for data your access will be logged.
- SQLMap is an automated testing tool. So it is actually sending a lot of requests in a short time, and this is not what a human would do.
  So it is likely to generate a very distinctive pattern regarding the *timing* of the requests.

Answer (score 0):

This is an odd question. If you are a legitimate pentester I would think you would already know the answer to this. I would recommend you test only on your own machines or machines you have permission to test until you build enough experience that this question is no longer an issue for you.

Comment: I'n not a pentester yet. But i want to be. I'm trying to learn some importent points. Searching and trying. That's just it.